# Why do I get a blank for every const char* and 0 for every int in this program in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

So i have the following file[image]

and basically what I want to do is read each line break it apart depending on the dots, print each team's name and for each member of a team i have i want to print out their names and other ints they have. My code is this:

```
int main () {
int x;
int y;
int j;
int t;
const char* pos;
const char* nam;
const char* line;
vector<const char*> v;
string str;
ifstream myfile ("data.txt");//opens file
if (myfile.is_open())//if you can open the file
{
while ( getline (myfile,str,'.') )//reads each line and breakes it apart based on the '.'
{
    line=str.c_str();
    v.push_back(line);//puts each field in a vector
 }
myfile.close();
const char* lim="Team Name";
const char* name=v[1];
cout<<"team one"<<name<<endl;
int i=2;
while((i<v.size())&&(v[i]!=lim)){//adds the players for the first team
        pos=v[i];
        i++;
        nam=v[i];
        i++;
        x=atoi(v[i]);//gets the x position from string to int
        i++;
        y=atoi(v[i]);//gets the y position from string to int
        i++;
        j=atoi(v[i]);//gets the jnum position from string to int
        i++;
        t=atoi(v[i]);//gets the targetline position from string to int
        cout<<"position: "<<pos<<" name: "<<nam<<" x: "<<x<<" y: "<<y<<" jnum: "<<j<<" targ: "<<t<<endl;
        i++;
}
i++;
const char* name2=v[i];
cout<<"team two"<<name2<<endl;
i++;
lim="end";
while((i<v.size())&&(v[i]!=lim)){//adds the players for the second team
       pos=v[i];
        i++;
        nam=v[i];
        i++;
        x=atoi(v[i]);//gets the x position from string to int
        i++;
        y=atoi(v[i]);//gets the y position from string to int
        i++;
        j=atoi(v[i]);//gets the jnum position from string to int
        i++;
        t=atoi(v[i]);//gets the targetline position from string to int
        cout<<"position: "<<pos<<" name: "<<nam<<" x: "<<x<<" y: "<<y<<" jnum: "<<j<<" targ: "<<t<<endl;
        i++;
}

  return 0;
}
}
```

However my code does not read everything properly and in the end it prints a blank for every const char* and 0 for every int. I had tried a similar code to this before with string instead of const char* and it worked however the program.exe stopped working after reading and printing the data. With this aproach the program.exe doesnt stop working but like I mentioned it doesnt work properly. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I think the downvotes on your question can be attributed to your ambiguous question title that, if searched using google, would return hundreds of viable results.

Comment: You could also use more descriptive variable names.  Names like `t`, `x`, etc. convey no meaning whatsoever.  Having descriptive names will help you understand what you're writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `while`:

```
while (getline(myfile,str,'.'))//reads each line and breakes it apart based on the '.'
        {
            line=str.c_str();
            v.push_back(line);//puts each field in a vector
        }
```

You set the pointer variable `const char* line`. But it contains the address obtained from `str` which probably has the same address each time.

So you end up with a vector of pointers all pointing to (probably) the same thing.

> doesnt it change everytime since it reads a new string from the file
>   each time?

The value it points to does change, but there is no guarantee that the compiler will use a new pointer. In fact, when `str` goes out of scope we now have a pointer to something that is not guaranteed to exist. We're on the train of undefined behavior and it is a train you don't want to be on. At least in this program `str` remains in scope, but this approach could easily go wrong.

> if no how would I be able to get it updated everytime?

Replace each instance of `const char*` with `std::string` and use `c_str()` when needed.

Comment: doesnt it change everytime since it reads a new string from the file each time? if no how would I be able to get it updated everytime? thanks for answering btw